# HTML input elements and Javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make all my HTML input elements change according to an onclick Javascript function and prevent them from changing again after a click event. My problem is that all the input elements change if only one of them is clicked on. Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="playerMove('button1')"/><input type="button" id="button2" onclick="playerMove('button2')"/><input type="button" id="button3" onclick="playerMove('button3')"/>
<input type="button" id="button4" onclick="playerMove('button4')"/><input type="button" id="button5" onclick="playerMove('button5')"/><input type="button" id="button6" onclick="playerMove('button6')"/>
<input type="button" id="button7" onclick="playerMove('button7')"/><input type="button" id="button8" onclick="playerMove('button8')"/><input type="button" id="button9" onclick="playerMove('button9')"/>
```

Here is my Javascript function:

```
function playerMove() {

    document.getElementById("button1").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button2").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button3").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button3").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button4").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button4").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button5").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button5").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button6").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button6").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button7").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button7").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button8").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button8").disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById("button9").value = "X";
    document.getElementById("button9").disabled = "disabled";

  }
```

Comment: ... and that's when you learn to use loops. And maybe jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply with jQuery:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).val("X");
});
```

This will dynamically add an `onclick` event listener to each `<input type="button" />` to automatically turn on the `disabled` attribute. No function nor `onclick` attributes required.

---

If you don't want to use / don't know how to use jQuery, then here's a plain JS representation of the above code:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.disabled = "disabled";
        this.value = "X";
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you want `.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @PaulS. Ooops I'll fix that. Thanks.

Comment: I also don't think this is what OP wants, reads like setting everything is **not** intended behaviour

Comment: @PaulS. Oops sorry again. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

change your `js` function like this

```
   function playerMove(button) {
        document.getElementById(button).value = "X";
        document.getElementById(button).disabled = "disabled"; 
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. He just missed the function variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using single `onclick` handler attached to `window` ; if `event.target` of `click` is `INPUT` element and `event.target` is not disabled , set `event.target` `value` to `"x"` , `disabled` property to `true`

```js
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" 
      && /^button\d+$/.test(e.target.id)
      && !e.target.disabled) {
    e.target.disabled = true;
    e.target.value = "x"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" />
<input type="button" id="button2" />
<input type="button" id="button3" />
<input type="button" id="button4" />
<input type="button" id="button5" />
<input type="button" id="button6" />
<input type="button" id="button7" />
<input type="button" id="button8" />
<input type="button" id="button9" />
```

Comment: As you're being as broad-reaching (listening on `window`) you may want to be more specific than a test for `<input>`. Maybe also test _type="button"_ etc

Comment: @PaulS. Added check for `id` beginning with "button" , ending with digit

Answer (score 1):

Consider attaching your event handlers entirely in *JavaScript*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () { // after page loaded (i.e. elements exist)
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(             // for each
        document.querySelectorAll('.my_awesome_buttons'), // of the awesome buttons
        function (button) {                   // call it "button" and do the following
            button.addEventListener(          // when it gets
                'click',                      // clicked
                function (e) {                // do your thing to it
                    this.value = "X";
                    this.disabled = "disabled";
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button2" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button3" class="my_awesome_buttons"/>
<input type="button" id="button4" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button5" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button6" class="my_awesome_buttons"/>
<input type="button" id="button7" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button8" class="my_awesome_buttons"/><input type="button" id="button9" class="my_awesome_buttons"/>
```

- [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

  - Which gets [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)ed on a *NodeList* in this example